# Reference request: “A random integral and Orlicz spaces”

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

I need to find the following paper:
“K. Urbanik and WA Woyczynski, A random integral and Orlicz spaces, Bulletin de l'Académie Polonaise des Sciences, Série des sciences mathématiques, astronomiques et physiques, 15 (1967), p. 161-169.”
It is possible to find it on the internet?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find it on the internet so I uploaded it here: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20221126nnUfCto7

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: link broken, see https://mathoverflow.net/q/459824/11260